# jQuery slideToggle Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, for-loop, dynamic, kendo-ui, slidetoggle

I am trying to implement a toggle button that allows the user to collapse or expand the vertical Kendo UI Menus dynamically.  I got the initial program working when I hard code the slideToggle.  However, as soon as I try to add logic for a simple loop to initialize the slideToggle to each menu, the program breaks.  There seems to be a problem with a counter variable within an array (i.e., the array of strings that represents the classes of each menu). Is there something I am doing wrong here? I am providing the example code below in my JSFiddle; you'll noticed that when you uncomment the hard coded section it works, but the section that I want to work includes the loop logic.  Thank you in advance for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/brandonq/KE8GX/3/

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//               This harcode works            //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*
        $("#menu1").click(function () {
          $(".hide1").slideToggle("slow");
        });

        $("#menu2").click(function () {
           $(".hide2").slideToggle("slow");
        }); 

*/

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//               This is what I want           //
//                but doesn't work             //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// array of the classes assigned to each table
var temp = ["hide1", "hide2"];

   for (z = 1; z <= hides.length; z++) {
      $("#menu" + z).click(function () {
      // The count variable z somehow breaks the tables
      $("." + temp[z - 1]).slideToggle("slow");

      // This below works for one table (the left one)
      // $("." + temp[0]).slideToggle("slow");
      // so when you increment that array of strings, jquery
      // doesn't like it
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that your elements aren't being assigned in the click function until the click function is being fired, which makes z = 3 because it's already been all the way through the loop. So it's trying to find `$('.' + temp[3-1])` which is undefined.

To fix this, what I've done instead is attach the function to all the `.k-items` that were not `.k-first`:

```
for (z = 1; z <= temp.length; z++) {
    $("#menu" + z).click(function () {
        $('li.k-item:not(.k-first)', this).slideToggle('slow');
    });
}
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/KE8GX/4/)

And you could actually even drop the for loop if you used this instead:

```
$("ul.menu").click(function () {
    $('li.k-item:not(.k-first)', this).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/KE8GX/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been stuck on this forever! Much appreciated, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

One problem and one mistake...

Mistake: you wrote `for (z = 1; z <= hides.length; z++) {` when it should be `for (z = 1; z <= tables.length; z++) {` i.e. iterate on `tables` and not in `hides`.

Problem (the actual error) the value of `z` in the event handler is the last value and not the value of each element. Try changing every `.hide1` and `.hide2` by `.hide` and then your code should be:

```
// array of the classes assigned to each table
for (z = 1; z <= tables.length; z++) {
    $("#menu" + z).click(function () {
        // The count variable z somehow breaks the tables
        $(".hide", this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/KE8GX/6/

Or as @Samsquanch suggests removing the loop as:

```
// array of the classes assigned to each table
$(".menu").click(function () {
    $(".hide", this).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

In a much concise code. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/KE8GX/8/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation OnaBai! Your answer has helped me understand what I did wrong. Much appreciated, thanks again!